# Next.js 13 Is it possible to receive the response value received from the middleware from the server component?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using Next.js version 13.4, can't middleware.ts request the backend and use the received information in the page component?
Currently, the response value itself is being rendered in the browser.

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname, searchParams } = request.nextUrl;
  if (pathname === "/admin") {
    console.log("admin 페이지에서 실행중!");
    let refreshTokenObj = request.cookies.get("refreshToken");
    let accessTokenObj = request.cookies.get("accessToken");
    let refreshToken = refreshTokenObj?.value;
    let accessToken = accessTokenObj?.value;

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/users/verifyadmin", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });

    const data = await res.json();
    const { isAdmin } = data;

    return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ success: isAdmin, message: "success" })
    );

  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/email-login:path", "/", "/register:path", "/admin"],
};
```

[image]

Comment: No. Middleware runs much earlier in the chain than the render process of a component, there is no way to return a response from the middleware to the component. But you could use a header/cookie to access the result.